# setting default.aspx as homepage not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have set default.aspx page as a homepage using SharePoint Designer.
So if I hit this page below its all good
/sites/intranetdev/default.aspx

But when I click on the logo area to get to the homepage it takes me to the below
/sites/intranetdev/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx

How do I get rid of the start.aspx page?
I also notices if I make changes to the master pages it doesn't reflect in the start.aspx page.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 you get start.aspx because of the feature *Minimal Download strategy*.
You could disable this feature by going to settings.

Site Settings > Site Actions > Manage Site Features > Then, deactivate "Minimal Download Strategy" feature.